# Javascript error: function XXXX() not defined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I added a javascript function in a page

```
 <head>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        function show_Alert(error)
        {
           alert(error);
         }
    </script>
</head>
```

and on button click I am doing this

```
Protected void btn_Click(object o,Eventargs e)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.AppendLine("show_Alert('XYZ error')");
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"Alert",str.ToString(),true);
}
```

But it throws JS error show_Alert is not defined :(

Any Idea, what is wrong here??

Thanx

Comment: Sorry That was not a issue, I am editing question

Answer (score 4):

Your script tag is wrong.
Change it to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

---

However, I don't think that's the issue.
I suspect that `RegisterStartupScript` is emitting its `<script>` block before the one with your function, so that it ends up calling the function before it exists.
Check where each `<script>` is in the rendered source.

Comment: SLaks RegisterStartupScript  creates new <script> block and not in a head. I think that is a problem.

Comment: If it's after the `<head>`, it shouldn't be a problem.  Put a normal `alert()` call at the beginning of each script and check what order they're alerted

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `<script>` element is valid, like this:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function show_Alert(error)
    {
      alert(error);
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

If it's not well formed, or the `type` is unrecognized (your case has both) then the script inside will be ignored, since the browser doesn't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    protected void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var str = "XYZ Error";
        var script = new StringBuilder();
        script.AppendFormat("showAlert('{0}');",
            HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(str)
        );
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", script.ToString(), true);
    }
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showAlert(error) {
            alert(error);
        }    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Btn" runat="server" Text="Click me" OnClick="BtnClick" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

A very important thing to pay attention to is to properly encode the string you are passing to the `showAlert` function. Notice that it is [encoded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode.aspx):

```
script.AppendFormat("showAlert('{0}');",
    HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(str)
);
```

If you don't encode it and the string contains some special characters like `'` for instance, your script will break.

Comment: HttpUtility doesn't have any option of JavaScriptStringEncode :(

Comment: @BreakHead, yeah that's .NET 4.0. You could use `new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(str)` as an equivalent in older versions of .NET.